# Control collectionView Scrolling from within collectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to stop my collection view from scrolling by writing code inside the collection view Cell .swift file. I want to be able to stop the scrolling when the user taps a button in the cell and then allow scrolling when the button is pressed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom delegate for your cell

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func cellDidSetScrolling(enabled: Bool)
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    // ....
}
```

Assign delegate to cell in `cellForItem`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // dequeue cell and assign delegate
    var cell: CustomCell?
   cell.delegate = self
   return cell
}
```

Call cell delegate on button action. Uses `button.tag` to determine `enabled` value

```
func buttonAction() {
    button.tag = button.tag == 0 ? 1 : 0 // toggle value
    delegate?.cellDidSetScrolling(enabled: button.tag == 1)
}
```

Implement delegate in `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate {

    func cellDidSetScrolling(enabled: Bool) {
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = enabled
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome. What does it mean if button.tag equals to 1?

Comment: The code will toggle the value of isScrollEnabled. That is, if scrolling if enabled, button tap will disabled it, and viceversa.

Comment: I'm asking something different. Correct me if I'm wrong: by default the button tag is set to `0` (I mean you don't need to give it an initial value. right)...so once it's clicked you set it to `1` and make your decision of `isScrollEnabled` based on that...you're basically abusing the tag property to do this manipulation...

Comment: Exactly. Alternatively you can simply add a variable to store the state of the button (:

Comment: I'm with jože. I don't understand why that's an abuse of tag. Tag is there to use anyway you wish. You're the only one who changes it after all.